# Is there a way to run 1 test-group multiple times with some selected methods using TestNG XML file?

Tags: java, testng, grouping

I have a group called 'base application group' which consist of 3 test methods:

```
Test a(groups = "base application group"), 
Test b(groups = "base application group") AND 
Test c(groups = "base application group").
```

Now, say that I only want to run Test a() and want to exclude rest of the methods from the group. I know how to do this in XML file. Now the real question is How can I run this group with every class in the XML File, provided I have 10 classes in XML file and this group should be executed 10 times?

So far, I have tried doing this with include and exclude tags at class level but I dont want to do it 10 times in my XML file. I have also tried  tag and Meta Group but that doesn't give me the desired output.

Here is my xml code atm:

```
<suite name ="Footer Suite" >
<test name ="Footer Tests" verbose ="2" >
    <classes>
        <class name ="it.org.techtime.jira.easysso.seleniumtests.footertests.MainAdminScreenTests">
            <methods>
                <exclude name ="Test b"/>
                <exclude name ="Test c"/>
            </methods>
        </class>
        <class name ="it.org.techtime.jira.easysso.seleniumtests.footertests.MainAdminScreenTests">
            <methods>
                <exclude name ="Test b"/>
                <exclude name ="Test c"/>
            </methods>
        </class>
    </classes>
</test>
```

I expect 'base application group' to run 10 times and also want only Test a() to run from the group. Not to forget that I want to achieve this from XML file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do this out of the box with TestNG. There's no mechanism that basically iterates a bunch of tests that belong to a group, `n` times.

The only way to do this is to do this is to manually duplicate the `<test>` tags, which as you pointed out is a manual process and needs the suite xml to be changed and checked-in every time.

All said and done, TestNG still lets you do this by doing the following.

1. Make sure you are depending on TestNG `7.0.0-beta7` (latest as of today)
2. Build an implementation of `org.testng.IAlterSuiteListener` using which you can programmatically alter your suite file and add/remove/update anything in it.

Here's an example of a listener that does what you are asking for.

```java
import java.util.List;
import org.testng.IAlterSuiteListener;
import org.testng.ITestContext;
import org.testng.TestListenerAdapter;
import org.testng.xml.XmlClass;
import org.testng.xml.XmlGroups;
import org.testng.xml.XmlSuite;
import org.testng.xml.XmlTest;

public class MultiRunner extends TestListenerAdapter implements IAlterSuiteListener {

  @Override
  public void alter(List<XmlSuite> suites) {
    XmlSuite xmlsuite = suites.get(0);
    XmlTest xmltest = xmlsuite.getTests().get(0);
    XmlGroups xmlgroups = xmltest.getXmlGroups();
    List<XmlClass> xmlclasses = xmltest.getClasses();
    int iteration = Integer.parseInt(System.getProperty("iterations", "2"));
    String name = xmltest.getName();
    for (int i=1; i<= iteration; i++) {
      XmlTest test = new XmlTest(xmlsuite);
      test.setName(name + "_" + i);
      test.setGroups(xmlgroups);
      test.setXmlClasses(xmlclasses);
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void onStart(ITestContext testContext) {
    System.err.println("Commencing execution of [" + testContext.getName() + "]");
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your time and response. I will implement this and will get back to you asap. I already knew it, that there is no direct mechanism to achieve what I'm asking for. That is why popped this question here just in case, if anyone has done it as I had no idea how to achieve it. I also went through the testNG google forum and posted the same in the group but unfortunately, hasn't been approved yet. I also have a couple of more questions which I have posted in the Google forum but hasn't been approved yet. Once again thank you for your response.

Comment: Pls don't forget to accept the answer. That way the question gets closed as well.

Comment: Yes, I will accept it if it works as expected. I just need to implement the solution. Sorry, a bit stuck up with work right now. I will do it asap.